# sum for every row values through columns pandas

Tags: python, aggregate

This is my dataframe and I want to sum for every row values through columns A,B,C,D and append column 'Summ'

```html
A B C D Summ
0 1 1 0 0 1+1+0+0
1 0 0 1 1 0+0+1+1
2 0 0 1 0 0+0+1+0
3 1 1 1 1 1+1+1+1
4 1 0 1 0 1+0+1+0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['Summ'] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

or better:

```
df.loc[:, 'Summ'] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

or for a subset of columns

```
cols = ['A','B']
df.loc[:, 'Summ'] = df[cols].sum(axis=1)
```